# Refresh query table VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2016 workbook with 2 external data sources (both towards the same Excel file).

One connection is for simple query table and other a pivot table. I have set up VBScript to launch a macro within this workbook to refresh both external datasources; add timestamp  & save.

Things look to be working with the exception of query table ("X") which is not refreshed (also located in Sheet 2 as is the pivot table).

Is `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` **not** supposed to update query tables, but work exclusively with pivot tables or am  I missing some code? Running `Data - Refresh All` manually from Excel does not refresh the query table either, although `Right click - Refresh` on the table does.

How could I incorporate the query table refresh in this code?

```
Sub Update()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotCache.Refresh

With Range("M12")
.Value = Now()
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel or Office?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's Excel 2016 in the Office 365 package.

Comment: Try adding Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic before running the refresh

Comment: Oops, stupid mistake on my part as the workbook is still work in progress. I unchecked the "Refresh this connection on Refresh All" checkmark from the query table connection, hence missing out on this one. Thanks for the input though!